# iFrame CSS Issue (possible focus)

Tags: css, iframe

I've created a page (http://testsite.motorcommerce.co.uk/bestvandeals/_dev_php/ad/test-3) which is working perfectly across all browsers except from IE11. When using IE11, the embedded iframe on the right side seems to focus on the input and hide the labels to the left. I've tried everything I can possibly think of to fix this issue but cannot seem to get a working solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Not sure why exactly, but it's the positioning of the table itself.  If you look at your #form1 CSS rules, and change the left property from 0 to 150px, you'll see that the labels appear..

Comment: Have you written browser specific hacks ?? cause in ie the width of fields_wrapper is 900 and in chrome it is 400px.

Comment: Added a left property and it is still in the same position. I haven't written any CSS hacks but that might be CSS from the iframe (allclients.com) - I only have limited CSS capability in their website.

Comment: If I add the CSS using the developer tool it appears fixed, however when actually applying these rules they don't appear to fix the problem. It looks like it's focusing on a particular element. I'll turn on the overflow if possible so you can see what I mean.

EDIT - if you take a look now you'll see the horizontal scroll is going to the center by default.